# Wide Angle Camera being default in all the web browsers without Focus

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I am working on building a web application that captures the image of certain labels. In most of the android and ios devices, the default camera is a 1X camera. But in Samsung phones, it is a 0.5X camera. This results in blurry images.

Note: This issue is mentioned here also.(https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Note10/Camera/m-p/833264)

Also for images related to this refer to this URL.
https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S-Phones/Wide-Angle-Camera-being-default-in-all-the-web-browsers-without/m-p/1007084

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck4Pp.jpg)
This issue seems to appear in S9 also. Please suggest a workaround or correct this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the media constraint like below to set the focal length/zoom and avoid x0.5

```
videoConstraints: {
        advanced: [
          {
            zoom: 1
          }
        ]
      }
```